# Exceptions "no such element" for automotive sessions in Browserstack for GREEN tests with usage of selenide and testng

Tags: selenium, saucelabs, browserstack, selenide

My selenium tests are green but in Browserstack session I see some exceptions about "no such element" in log. Can't find such errors in maven/testng full logs, tried to run with -e -X parameters - the same, tests are green, no exception.

Browserstack log looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/tatianadurova/fac5699ba346ba84a1698ae0d254e625).

Maven log looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/tatianadurova/e7a6faca8d90026ff684f96ddf8e0858).

Comment: What does your test code look like? Are you failing the tests when these exceptions occur?

Comment: No, tests are green actually. It is selenium tests with a lot of Javascript executions and Javascript asserts. It's strange that I see such exceptions only  in browserstack, I tried to run exactly the same tests by exactly the same maven commands and I don't see similar exceptions in maven log.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I could see only one reason - sometimes Browserstack environments are slow and internet speed is not fast. Tests that ran for 20-30 seconds locally sometimes ran longer than a minute on BS.

So general advise for Browserstack test runs - make webdriver's implicit waits longer and in critical places add explicit waits. And do it from the same beginning of test implementation and there will not be any problems later. If cloud is fast you won't loose any second, if cloud is slow you won't get "no such element" exception.